# Finite subspace of norm space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(V,||\cdot||)$ be norm space (not necessarily finite-dimensional) and $W\subset V$ finite-dimensional vector subspace (V$\neq$W), I need to prove that:

$$\exists v\in V:d(v,W)=1$$
$$d(a,B)=\inf_{b\in B} \{d(a,b)\}$$

The only thing I can think which might help is that W is closed and the
Norm function is continuous, however I cannot seem to get beyond that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have guessed it right that the norm function is continuous. You need to use intermediate value property of continuous functions.

Comment: I do not understand how can i show that there exists some w's in W such that ||v-w|| >1  and some w's with ||v-w||<1...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** No need for anything fancy like the intermediate value property. Has nothing to do with continuity: Just show that $d(tx,W) = td(x,W)$ for $t>0$...

Comment: What does it have to do with the existence of  v∈V:d(v,W)=1?

Comment: If $d(x,V)>0$ then there exists $t>0$ such that $td(x,V)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $W$ is closed because it is finite dimensional.

Let $x \notin W$ thus we have that $d(x,W)=t>0$

So from definition of $d$ exists a sequence $w_n \in W$ such that $t \leq ||x-w_n||< t+\frac{1}{n}$

For all $n \in \Bbb{N}$ we have that $$||w_n-w_1|| \leq ||w_n-x||+||x-w_1||<t+\frac{1}{n}+t+1\leq2t+2$$

Thus $w_n \in B(w_1,2t+2)$(closed ball) which is a compact set because $W$ is finite dimensional.

Thus exists a subsequence $w_{n_k}$  such that $w_{n_k} \to w_0 \in W$

Then $||x-w_0||=\lim_{n \to +\infty}||x-w_{n_k}||=t$

Now take $z=\frac{(x-w_0)}{t}$ and $||z||=1$

Also for every $w \in W$  we have $$||z-w||=||\frac{x-(w_0+tw)}{t}|| \geq \frac{d(x,W)}{t}=1$$ because $w_0+tw \in W$

Thus $d(z,W) \geq 1$ and also $d(z,W) \leq ||z-0||=||z||=1$

Thus $d(z,W)=1$ and $||z||=1$